# custom attribute value from an function runned

Tags: jquery

On clicking an button, i want to add an number to attibute of a div.
Attribute is "data-count"
"insert" is button.
Ineed the function's value is theTotal to be added to the attribute value.

```
var theTotal = 4;
$('#insert').click(function(){

   theTotal = Number(theTotal) + Number($(this).val());

    $('#total').attr('data-count', '100');

});
```

Currently on clicking insert button value shows as 100 as i have entered manual value. How to get function's theTotal value there.

Comment: Just do `.attr('data-count', theTotal)`.

Comment: @Webgen given the fact that you are using jQuery, why don't you just do: `.data('count', theTotal)`? That would result in the HTML attribute: `data-count="123"` ( 123 being your total )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To further elabourate on my answer: all you need to do is to pass the `totalNumber` variable into the second argument of the `.attr()` method, i.e.:

```
$('#total').attr('data-count', theTotal);
```

Also, you don't need to use `Number()` to convert a string into a number: using the unary operator `+` will do the job. In addition, since `theTotal` is already a number, you don't need to convert it further. In fact, your code can be simplified as such:

```
var theTotal = 4;
$('#insert').click(function(){

    theTotal += +this.value;

    $('#total').attr('data-count', theTotal);
});
```

Comment: i needed help in customising this. Like with currency symbol before the total or so. Can help?